# How do I clear a device context?

Tags: c++, winapi, device

I'm not sure if this is something that is possible.  But basically the gist of what I need is that a bunch of stuff in my Win32 program is drawn to hWnd through a device context during WM_PAINT.  Then through a separate function, I have more stuff drawn to hWnd through the SAME DC.  Unfortunately since I use the same DC, the stuff drawn during WM_PAINT is still held in the DC, and is therefore subsequently copied again through my function.

What I need to do is clear the contents of my device context at the end of WM_PAINT or the beginning of my function so that the stuff isn't copied twice.

Comment: The  only way its drawn through the *same* DC is if you pass it the DC loaded from your `BeginPaint()`. Are you doing that? (I hope so, btw).  If the purpose is to break down what is drawn in your paint handler vs what is drawn in your direct-function and eliminate potential duplicity, I would suggest you add a param to your function that hints it to know it is being WM_PAINT-response invoked. Therefore it knows what NOT to render (because it already has-been or will-be in your paint handler).

Comment: You have a drastically wrong mental model of what a DC is.  Surely what you want to clear here are the pixels stored in video memory.  You do so with FillRect() or PatBlt().

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you do the entire drawing in WM_PAINT handler ?in the second drawing how do you draw?may be using GetDC to get the device context and draw, right?
The problem is that when you draw outside the WM_PAINT handler, it get erased when the window need to repaint, and the WM_PAINT drawing trump your GetDC based painting, unless you use a bitmat to keep the current context's content

Comment: Well I call my function from inside WM_PAINT, so it should run whenever the window redraws.  But because I'm using the same device context for both, some things are being drawn twice.

Comment: if you paste the source, i can fix it for you

Comment: I posted a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14099434/win32-why-is-nothing-being-drawn-to-the-screen

Answer (score 1):

Do all of your drawing to an off-screen bitmap whenever you need to while outside of `WM_PAINT`, then simple copy the current bitmap to the `HWND` inside of `WM_PAINT`.