# Win32 - why is nothing being drawn to the screen?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to use an off-screen buffer so that I can keep track of changes to the screen before/after WM_PAINT and just copy them through one line in WM_PAINT.  Here's some code I have to set up the graphics:

```
hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
hdcmem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
hbcmem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcmem);

// Load bitmaps
bg = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BACKGROUND));
side = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_SIDEINFO));
mainCont = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_GAME_CONT));
if(bg == NULL || side == NULL || mainCont == NULL)
            ThrowError("A bitmap failed to load.");

// Background
hdcold = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hbcmem, bg);
BitBlt(hdcmem, 0, 0, 237, 196, hbcmem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
BitBlt(hdcmem, 237, 0, 237, 196, hbcmem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
BitBlt(hdcmem, 237 * 2, 0, 237, 196, hbcmem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
BitBlt(hdcmem, 0, 196, 237, 196, hbcmem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
BitBlt(hdcmem, 237, 196, 237, 196, hbcmem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
BitBlt(hdcmem, 237 * 2, 196, 237, 196, hbcmem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

// Side Info
hdcold = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hbcmem, side);
BitBlt(hdcmem, 339, 26, 154, 300, hbcmem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

// Main Game Container
hdcold = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hbcmem, mainCont);
BitBlt(hdcmem, 26, 26, 300, 300, hbcmem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
```

hdc, hdcmem, hbcmem, hdcold, bg, side, and mainCont are declared previously.  Their scope includes everything in this file (including this code and the code in WM_PAINT).

Here's the code in WM_PAINT:

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 518, 401, hdcmem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
```

For some reason, nothing is being drawn to the screen.  I'm racking my brain trying to figure it out.  A pointer in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: And you have checked that WM_PAINT is actually being called? Perhaps you need a Invalidate() to make the screen update?

Comment: I've checked.  It's definitely being called.

Comment: Very glad it works for you. Please ensure your `hdc` in that `WM_PAINT` handler is coming from `hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps)`. *That* is the one you should be blitting into from your `hdcmem` during WM_PAINT processing. (and note, it is invalid as soon as you invoke `EndPaint()`, which is correct behavior).

Comment: Well previously I defined hdc as GetDC(hWnd).  So that means that after EndPaint() I can still draw into hdc.  Or should I not do that?

Comment: Sry, was away from my desk. No, you should not even *need* the client DC once your memory DC is setup (see the updated answer below). You should use the DC from BeginPaint() in a paint handler. Calling EndPaint() will release it for you. You don't have to invoke ReleaseDC(), in other words, but you *do* in the initial setup code in the answer to this question. Again, see the updated answer below.

Comment: Ideally any time you need to paint the client area the content of what needs to be painted should already be rendered in your compatible mem-dc and bitmap (because you just finished writing it there). At that point simply `InvalidateRect()` with the box size you need repainted and let your paint handler take over through normal messaging. In that you'll use the hdc from `BeginPaint()`, do you BitBlt from your updated mem-dc and bitmap, then `EndPaint()` which validates the window. You can improve this performance even further by using the box in the paint struct as your BitBlt target coords.

Comment: You should paint into the DC returned by `BeginPaint` in your `WM_PAINT` handler. Other parts of the system (such as `PrintWindow`) rely on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a compatible bitmap for your memory device context first, then select that bitmap to the memory dc and it should work !

```
hdc = GetDC(hWnd); // used only to create compatibles.
hdcmem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
hbcmem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);

// Create client-area-sized compatible bitmap.
RECT rc;
GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
HBITMAP hbm_memdc = CreateComptibleBitmap(hdc, rc.right, rc.bottom);
HBITMAP hbm_memdc_old = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcmem, hbm_memdc)

ReleaseDC(hdc); // this no longer needed

// now start rendering into hdcmem...
```

You'll want to keep the old bitmap handle selected out to put it back before destroying your custom one on shutdown. How you manage that is entirely up to you.

Comment: What's the difference between that and what I did?

Comment: The default bitmap in a newly created DC isn't viable for what you're doing. You need a CreateCompatibleBitmap() then select it into your memoryDC. Its the thing you're being drawing *on*. The DC is what holds it while you do so. From the MS docs on CreateCompatibleDC() : "Before an application can use a memory device context for drawing operations, it must select a bitmap of the correct width and height into the device context. This may be done by using CreateCompatibleBitmap to specify the height, width, and color organization required in the function call."

Comment: Each device context must contain a bitmap of the dimensions of the window, the device context represents.When we do drawing, its the contents of this bitmap is changing.Unless you select this main bitmap u cannot do the drawing propely

Comment: Ok, that makes sense and seems to work, but It's rendering in black and white.

Comment: figured it out.  SelectObject() should have 'hdc' as the first parameter.  Not 'hdcmem'.

Comment: @BrianGradin yeah sorry that was my bad. It wasn't SelectObject() that was the problem, it was the CreateCompatibleBitmap() call. It was using the default bitmap in the mem-dc, which is a monochome mask bmp, as the model to replicate. Using the client DC prior to releasing it (its the last thing it is needed for, see the code above) is the right way to create a proper compatible bmp for this. Its been literally over a decade since I did this and its still a little foggy in my brain. I do remember the highlights, however.